# mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD on RPi4B and SD is perfectly working

Tags: pi-4, sd-card, boot-issues, bootloader

SD card is working fine, it is not dead.

Boot Diagnostics screen when sd card is not inserted
[image: Boot Diagnostics screen]

After inserting the sd card, it reboots and this is what it shows
[image: Boot error]

I tried flashing the same os image on multiple sd cards but the issue persists.
If it's a problem with sd card slot, is it possible to boot from usb?(tried but I get the diagnostics screen.)

Is my pi bricked?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `is it possible to boot from usb` should be, unless you specifically modified the bootloader to not try

Comment: Well it is not booting from usb, it says `insert SD-card`

Comment: Odd, pretty sure by 16/02/2021 the pi4 was able to boot from USB - have you tried multiple USB drives?

Comment: Yes, surprisingly it doesn't work :/